# Yocto. Number of packages in root file system image

Tags: image, package, yocto, figure, bitbake

Embedded Linux distro built here using Yocto.
The goal is to find out number of all software packages going into root file system image.
For this a look at few locations was taken:

output of

```
oe-pkgdata-util list-pkgs -r | wc -l
```

output of

```
oe-pkgdata-util list-pkgs | wc -l
```

the file

```
poky\build\tmp-glibc\deploy\licenses\targdvce-image-arch03-20180321164634\package.manifest
```

Figure reported by first one: 1946

Figure reported by second one: 1946

Figure reported by third one: 248

I wonder where the discrepancies from:

between third reporting and another ones, 248 vs. 1946

I wonder where the lack of discrepancy comes from:

`oe-pkgdata-util list-pkgs -r`  vs. `oe-pkgdata-util list-pkgs`

If, according to oe-pkgdata-util's help, the short option *-r* stand for "Show runtime package names instead of recipe-space package names" why its output does not deviate from invocation free of *-r* ?

Jethro version is in use.

Comment: `oe-pkgdata-util list-pkgs` does not list installed packages in a specific image.

Comment: Thanks, that answers one of asked questions.